# Assignment statement with AND operator

Tags: php, operators

Can any one explain me following construct.
I do googling for this about 2 hours but can't understand.

```
public function __construct($load_complex = true)
{
    $load_complex and $this->complex = $this->getComplex();
}
```

Comment: You may get probably logical error while you are putting Expression instead of assigning values to the VARIABLE on LEFT HAND SIDE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

PHP uses intelligent expression evaluation. If any of AND's operands evaluates to false, then there is no reason to evaluate other, because result will be false.

So if `$load_complex` is false there is no need to evaluate `$this->complex = $this->getComplex();`

This is some kind of workaround, but I do not suggest to use it, because it makes your code hard to read.

Specifically to your example `$this->complex = $this->getComplex()` if and only if `$load_complex` is set to true.

Comment: It's called "short circuit evaluation".

Answer (score 1):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/rFXJ6Rn9)**

> NOTE: If any one of *OPERAND* result becomes '*false*' in short
>   circuit **AND** evaluation means, the part of statement will be
>   **OMITTED** because there is no need to evaluate it.

Dont code like below line because, you may get probably logical
          error while you are putting Expression instead of assigning values
          to the variable on LEFT HAND SIDE...

```
 $load_complex and $this->complex = $this->getComplex();
```

I have modified below with conditinal statement for your needs...

```
if($load_complex and $this->complex) {
     $this->getComplex();
}
```